# trying to install openSuse Leap 15.3 alongside existing windows10 on my surface pro

Tags: windows, partitioning, opensuse, disk-management, storage-spaces

[Device Spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kqKW.png)

[Windows Spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqbzV.png)

[Disk Partition in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5QwL.png)

Now, when I restart and boot using a openSuse Leap 15.3 bootable USB, i expect to see a 100 GB disk that I could partition as required (root, home, swap etc). However, I see two disks of 470 GB, the meaning of which I dont understand. And worried that continuing with the opensuse recommendation will delete 400 GB of my data.

[Opensuze recommendation for disk management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05ybO.jpg), where I expect it to talk about the 100 GB of unallocated disk space. Instead it says delete the partition of 470 GB, which I do not know appeared from where (based on the disk partition I am seeing in Windows).

And if I try to modify the partitions using opensuse expert partitioner, [this is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfRUj.jpg)

I would like to keep my windows10, install opensuse on the 100GB unallocated space and be able to dualboot. I have absolutely no experience installing OS or disk partitions. Please advice.

Further research has lead me to believe that Windows is using something called a Storage Pool and I have in fact two physical hard drives [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQIDF.png).
Now what do I do?

Comment: If you don't have any experience at all I would recommend to practice on an non-critical system first to gain some experience, chances are high for data loss in this scenario. Don't forget to backup everything first before doing any changes. I'm not sure but I believe because of the pool setup the openSUSE installer can't see the 100 GB free space, those are free within the storage pool. Is it mandatory for you to have a dual-boot? Or would it be an alternative to have a virtual machine running Leap?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately I do need the dualboot and virtual machine is not an option.

Comment: @PratheekPonnuru - In that case you will want to disable BitLocker protection. Since you cannot disable Secure Boot on Surface Pro products you will want to use a Linux distribution that supports it.

Comment: I can disable Secure Boot. The problem is with the partition. I have tried disabling BitLocker, same issue.